# Dom manipulation in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I wanted to know, If we want to manipulate the DOM. Where we should do that.
Is it in a Controller or a directive or somewhere else ?
I have read somewhere that manipulating the DOM in controller should be avoided. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Angular JS Directive` for `DOM` manipulations. `DOM` Manipulations should not exist in **`Controllers`**, **`Services`** or anywhere else but in **`Directives`**.

One of the nicer features of `AngularJS` is the framework's ability to separate the roles of the model, the view, and the controller. The separation is clean enough that you shouldn't need to manipulate the `DOM` directly from code inside the controller. Instead, the controller only manipulates the model, which influences the view through data bindings and directives.  The end result is a clean and testable.

Take a look at this

**[Video](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-and-dom-manipulation/)** - This video tutorial covers manipulating the `DOM` in `AngularJS` using directives with a link function.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is: 
Dom manipulations **only** in directives.

[Read here](http://ng-learn.org/2014/01/Dom-Manipulations/)