# Where should I put the code to change class of the parent element in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a plugin to a larger application that uses Angular.
The plugin is basically an include in a larger HTML document.

I want to change class of the plugin's parent element.

I can't change parent HTML directly, so where should I put the code to do `addClass`?

Directive feels like an overkill (and it would either be very specific, or I would have to re-implement whole `ng-class`). But it might be a fair answer.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? Your plugin is a template, and is ngIncluded into a larger angular app?

Comment: Pretty much yes -- though I am not sure if they use `ngInclude` or a custom directive.

Comment: Well, a template with behavior definitely feels like a good place to use a directive to me! Could you combine your template, and the code to change the parent's class into a single directive for the app to use?

Comment: Note: I can include my own JS files into plugin (so its not pure `ngInclude`, there is a manifest that lists additional files). _Could you combine your template, and the code to change the parent's class into a single directive for the app to use?_ like that, no, as plugin support is abstracted, but I can pack directive js together with the template.

Comment: You can have a look into this question. Hope it will clarify you. 


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380573/dom-manipulation-in-angularjs/23380878?noredirect=1#23380878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think directive is a way to do it. From Angular's documentation:

> Manipulate DOM — Controllers should contain only business logic. Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects its testability. Angular has databinding for most cases and **directives to encapsulate manual DOM manipulation.**

Comment: What about services? `$window` and `$rootElement` seem pretty DOM-related to me.

Comment: Even though that advice is given all over the place, look at what things like ui-bootstrap do. Most of their directives use controllers and services to do the actual work. So this concept of "only do DOM manipulation in directives" is silly. But in this case, I think it is probably the right answer :)

Comment: I would say they only provide you with an access to those elements. You can inject those as dependencies into your directive and use it from there to modify the DOM.

Comment: @aet I have seen ui bootstrap using contolers to modify the model of a directive. For example tabs directive use controller to add tabs to a tabset, but I have not seen controller acting on an element. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Sure, dropdown.js is a perfect example: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/dropdown/dropdown.js

Comment: Well, it seems a directive is the right option, thanks.

Comment: Just for completeness, that what I ended up with: https://gist.github.com/ashmind/d58c65d198c193981969

Comment: @aet good point. However I will still argue it's a different case. The action is actually driven by the directive. This is directive controller, and it is bound to the directive. The same goes for the service, it is merely a way to cope with a global state of the drop down. I would say thus technically you're right, logically it is all driven by the directive, the controller and a service would not exist without it.